# Class active to anchor carousle slide

Tags: carousel, slide

I have various anchors to scroll through the slides of a carousel. Everything works fine, only I would like to use the automatic "active" class to change the style, I tried in various ways but I could not do it

```
<a data-target="#soluzioni_carousel" data-slide-to="1">1</a>
<a data-target="#soluzioni_carousel" data-slide-to="2">2</a>
<a data-target="#soluzioni_carousel" data-slide-to="3">3</a>
```

Comment: Can you specify which js library are you using and provide also the js code?
The anchors now seems all related to the same id.

Comment: i use carousel Bootstrap 4

Comment: Do you see the 'active' class appearing in the console when the slide changes?
What do you mean with change the style? Assign some css?

Comment: By the way this is a good read: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask